# Limit Minimum Count of Nested Fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a parent model and child model.

I want to make it mandatory that at least one child is created when a new parent is created.

I am using the nested_form gem and currently using this script to limit the number of children added per record.

```
$(function() {
var fieldsCount,
  maxFieldsCount = 4,
  $addLink = $('a.add_nested_fields');

function toggleAddLink() {
$addLink.toggle(fieldsCount <= maxFieldsCount)
}

$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function() {
fieldsCount += 1;
toggleAddLink();
});

$(document).on('nested:fieldRemoved', function() {
fieldsCount -= 1;
toggleAddLink();
});  

// count existing nested fields after page was loaded
fieldsCount = $('form .fields').length;
toggleAddLink();
})
```

Is there a way for me to also include a "minimum" requirement? Lets say (1) child? Basically remove the "remove link" if only (1) nested form is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I figured out on how to make sure at least one field is presented by removing the "Remove" link based on its count

```
  $(function() {
  var fieldsCount,
  maxFieldsCount = 2,
  $addLink = $('a.add_nested_fields');

  var mfieldsCount,
  minFieldsCount = 0, // placed at 0 because first object is auto built from controller
  $removeLink = $('a.remove_nested_fields');

  function toggleAddLink() {
  $addLink.toggle(fieldsCount <= maxFieldsCount)
 }

  function toggleRemoveLink() {
  $removeLink.toggle(mfieldsCount <= minFieldsCount)
  }

  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function() {
  fieldsCount += 1;
  toggleAddLink();
 });

 $(document).on('nested:fieldRemoved', function() {
 fieldsCount -= 1;
 toggleAddLink();
});

 $(document).on('nested:fieldRemoved', function() {
mfieldsCount -= 0;
toggleRemoveLink();
 });  

 // count existing nested fields after page was loaded
 fieldsCount = $('form .fields').length;
 toggleAddLink();

  mfieldsCount = $('form .fields').length;
  toggleRemoveLink();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call a build method inside your parent's controller in action new.
So, when you go parent/new, you will have one child already created. It's just like that:
@parent.children.build